# Set interval in chart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, charts

How can I set interval on Y axsis?

This is my partial view with chart:

```
@using TestProject.Models;

@{        
    var Chart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddLegend()
        .AddSeries(
            name: "USD",
            xValue: ViewBag.xValUsd,
            yValues: ViewBag.yValUsd,
            chartType: "Line")
        .SetYAxis("Белорусские рубли", ViewBag.MinValue, ViewBag.MaxValue)
        .Write();
}
```

Comment: which charting library is this?

Comment: @DanielA.White It's an HTML Helper https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart